# sharepoint 2010 quick launch issue

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise

I am not being able to see Recycle bin and All Site contents link  in quick launch in Sharepoint2010 Home page site.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Check style(CSS) for the class "**.s4-specialNavLinkList**" in rendered HTML. If it is "**display:none;**" then Create a new css file with the text below and upload to the site collections Style Library.

```
.s4-specialNavLinkList
{
   display: block;
}
```

Reference - https://anujpant.wordpress.com/2012/12/21/sharepoint-2010-publishing-portal-missing-quick-launch/

Please let me know if any concern.

Comment: Hi , mine is collaboration portal and I am not gettin any options